# creating javascript object literal of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I am from a classical OOO background and finding it difficult to understand the javascript object literal construction. I need a javascript variable containing an array of name value pairs. I should be able to push name, value pairs to the array through a function. SOmehow, I am finding it confusing to create such data structure. Could you please help me know the correct syntax for the same:

What I am looking for

```
var selectedItemArray = array of name, value pairs
```

and i should be able to

```
selectedItemArray.push(name, value);
```

and

```
selectedItemArray.get(index);



var tagArray = [];



for (var i in secondaryTagsArray) {
    tagArray.push({tagId:secondaryTagsArray[i].secondary_tag_id,
                   tagName:secondaryTagsArray[i].secondary_tag_name 
                   });
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Key-Value pairs can be created with JavaScript Objects, with Object lietral, like this

   ```
   {key: value}
   ```
2. Arrays can be created with Array literal (`[]`) or with `Array` constructor like this

   ```
   new Array(size);
   ```

You can use both of them, like this

```
var array = [];
array.push({key1: value1});
```

Since JavaScript arrays begin with index 0, you need to access the first element with index 0, second with 1 and so on.

```
console.log(array[0]);
```

will print the first key-value pair stored at index 0.

Comment: should the key be unique? What if I have to have same name but different values for each array item?

Comment: @user883561 Can you show some sample input? I might be able to help you understand better

Comment: Whatever you have done with `tagArray` is correct only. How is `secondaryTagsArray` defined?

Comment: Thanks. I will go ahead with the same implementation.

Comment: @user883561 If `secondaryTagsArray` is really an array, then you must use a for loop to iterate it, like this `for (var i = 0; i < secondaryTagsArray.length; i += 1) {`

Comment: A *single* pair would better be represented as `[key, value]` or `{key:1, value:5}`